# Kernel 4.2.3 in Ubuntu 14.04 with startup errors

Tags: kernel, radeon

From kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/..., I installed v4.2.3 on my 14.04 64bit system with AMD A8-6600K, integrated GPU Radeon HD8570D.

The system seems to run, uses the graphic driver “Gallium 0.4 on AMD ARUBA”. But, there are a couple of error messages at startup, too fast to write down.
In dmesg I find:

“radeon 0000:00:01.0: Direct firmware load for radeon/TAHITI_vce.bin failed with error -2”
“radeon 0000:00:01.0: radeon_vce: Can’t load firmware radeon/TAHITI_vce.bin”
“[drm:vce_v1_0_start [radeon]] *ERROR* VCE not responding, trying to reset the ECPU!!!”

Aside of that, everything seems to work fine, any idea what is wrong/can be done?

Comment: did you install `radeon` driver for kernel 4.x?

Comment: There is no standalone `radeon` driver`.

Comment: This kernel is not supported in Ubuntu. You need to install a supported kernel and `fglrx-updates` drivers.

Answer (score 0):

your graphics card driver isn't compatible with this kernel 
try this

Add either of the following repositories:
Stable: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
Beta: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fglrx gksu
sudo amdconfig --initial

Then reboot your system

Type: "gksu amdcccle"
to run AMD Catalyst Control Centre

Drivers are compatible with the following series of cards:
R9
R7
HD5xxx, HD6xxx, HD7xxx, HD8xxx
as well as APU based cards

I hope it helps :) have a nice day

Comment: The open-source drivers (Gallium...) should be optimized for the new 4.2 kernel as there are many improvements for APU realized from kernel  4.2 on. The proprietary AMD Catalyst is working up to 3.19, I read somewhere.

Maybe I need a ppa for the latest updates of the open-source drivers?

Comment: yeah maybe you need to update the repos but the instructions i gave totally works with readon cards

Comment: try again...
After some time and update to kernel 4.3.3, I tried the proprietary AMD driver:
Installed from repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa 
sudo apt-get install fglrx gksu produced an error message "ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.3.3-040303-generic is not supported. ..."
After restart it was not possible to login to the graphical desktop, so I removed fglrx (sudo apt-get remove fglrx) from terminal, and restarted.
Now, the error messages at startup no longer occur.
But, shouldn't the driver work for this kernel?